# How can I display the HTML of one cell in the adjacent cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

A very simple example can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10qUrVMFCdj_myc33uYPKxz_mDXzGhTLC-agh3P7s4XQ/edit#gid=0

Basically, I'd like to have column A feature all of the formatted text, and column B show the HTML version of the same text. Note: we really only need to know how to display whether something is bold.

Thanks to everyone who pitches in with their 2 cents! This community is remarkable.

Comment: Will the html text always utilize the same format? Do you only want part of the formatted text to be bold or keywords?

Comment: Also it's not clear which way you want to go. From A to B or B to A? This formula in column A will strip all the tags out of column B but without using scripts you can not bold partial words. `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"<[^>]*>",""))`

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you so much for your reply! We would like to take what is in Column A and generate what is in column B using a formula or script. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Oh I see, unfortunately that is not possible with an standard formula. There is no way to identify what is in bold. You're only option is to use script if at all possible and at the moment I am not familiar enough to attempt a script.